# right pad regex with spaces using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, padding

I have a file with two fields separated with `:`, both fields are varying length, second field can have all sort of characters(user input). I want the first field to be right padded with spaces to fixed length of 15 characters, for first field I have a working regex `@.[A-Z0-9]{4,12}`.

sample:

```
@ABC123:"wild things here"
@7X3Z:"":":@":";:*:-user input:""
@99999X999:"also, imagine: unicode, yay!"
```

desired output:

```
@ABC123        :"wild things here"
@7X3Z          :"":":@":";:*:-user input:""
@99999X999     :"also, imagine: unicode, yay!"
```

There is plenty of examples how to zero pad a number, but surprisingly not a lot about general padding a regex or a field, any help using (preferably) sed or awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl`:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/^[^:]+/sprintf("%-15s",$&)/e' ip.txt
@ABC123        :"wild things here"
@7X3Z          :"":":@":";:*:-user input:""
@99999X999     :"also, imagine: unicode, yay!"
```

The `e` flag allows you to use Perl code in replacement section. `$&` will have the matched portion which gets formatted by `sprintf`.

With `awk`:

```sh
# should work with any awk
awk 'match($0, /^[^:]+/){printf "%-15s%s\n", substr($0,1,RLENGTH), substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}'

# can be simplified with GNU awk
awk 'match($0, /^[^:]+/, m){printf "%-15s%s\n", m[0], substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}'
# or
awk 'match($0, /^([^:]+)(.+)/, m){printf "%-15s%s\n", m[1], m[2]}'
```

- `substr($0,1,RLENGTH)` or `m[0]` will give contents of first field. I have used `1` instead of the usual `RSTART` here since we are matching start of line
- `substr($0,RLENGTH+1)` will give rest of the line contents (i.e. from the first `:`)
- See [awk manual: String-Manipulation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for details about `match` function.

Comment: I was not sure how to approach this, awk - fields or sed - regex, so included both ways. I intend to use this under windows with lightweight tools, so a perl solution is suboptimal.

Comment: Oh ok, but with `sed` also you can use negated character class. I've also added `awk` solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another `awk` solution that would work with any version of awk:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} {$1 = sprintf("%-15s", $1)} 1' file

@ABC123        :"wild things here"
@7X3Z          :"":":@":";:*:-user input:""
@99999X999     :"also, imagine: unicode, yay!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding one more way of adding spaces to 1st columns here, though anubhava's answer with `sprintf` is better answer, adding is as an option here. Here I have created a variable named spaces, where one could define number of spaces which we need to add to it.

```
awk -v spaces="15" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {sub(/:/,sprintf("%"spaces-length($1)"s",":"))} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v spaces="15" '  ##Starting awk program from here, setting spaces to 15 here.
BEGIN{                ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.  
  FS=OFS=":"          ##Setting FS and OFS as colon here.
}
{
  sub(/:/,sprintf("%"spaces-length($1)"s",":")) ##Substituting colon first occurrence with spaces(left padding of spaces) along with colon here.
}
1                     ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe **anbhava**'s solution of

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} {$1 = sprintf("%-15s", $1)} 1' file
```

can be even further simplified as :

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{FS=OFS} $1=sprintf("%-15s",$1)'
```

the `{ }` and final `1` are optional